# mysql query doesn't work inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `isUserValid`(IN `facebookId` VARCHAR(20), IN `userAccessToken` TEXT)
    NO SQL
    COMMENT 'check if user is valid. return true or false'
Begin
    /* declare the select resluts variables*/   
    Declare accessToken TEXT;
    Declare expires datetime;

    /* fill the variables with saved user's access token an expires time*/
    Select Access_Token, Expires
    Into accessToken, expires
    From Users Where Facebook_Id = facebookId;      

    select expires,accessToken;
    /* If the saved access token and expires are valid return true */
    If (BINARY accessToken = userAccessToken And expires > now()) Then
        select true As isUserValid;
    Else
        select false As isUserValid;
    End If; 
End
```

for some reason the query:

```
/* fill the variables with saved user's access token an expires time*/
Select Access_Token, Expires
Into accessToken, expires
From Users Where Facebook_Id = facebookId;
```

return the Expires as null all the time.

When i'm running the same query outside of the procedure - it returns the Expires as a value...

I can't understand what is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Ok found it,
You must provide different names to variables and fields.

my expires is identical to Expires in the table, therefor it is always null.